# MySQL - AND query on joined table

Tags: mysql, join

I have a pretty long SQL query:

```
SELECT *, content.contentID AS thisID
FROM content
LEFT JOIN link_keywords ON content.contentID = link_keywords.contentID
LEFT JOIN link_countries ON content.contentID = link_countries.contentID
LEFT JOIN link_sections ON content.contentID = link_sections.contentID
WHERE status = '1' AND typeID = '1'
GROUP BY contentID
ORDER BY creationDate DESC
```

I get back a set of results, what I would like to do is display all results where `sectionID` (which comes from the link_sections join) is equal to both 3 or 4. In other words, all results that are in both section 3 and 4.

The following query doesn't return back anything, presumably this is because it is checking for a single row with `sectionID` equal to 3 and 4. What I need is any `content.contentID` with `sectionID` equal to 3 and 4.

```
SELECT *, content.contentID AS thisID
FROM content
LEFT JOIN link_keywords ON content.contentID = link_keywords.contentID
LEFT JOIN link_countries ON content.contentID = link_countries.contentID
LEFT JOIN link_sections ON content.contentID = link_sections.contentID
WHERE status = '1' AND typeID = '1' AND (sectionID = '3' AND sectionID = '4')
GROUP BY contentID
ORDER BY creationDate DESC
```

Comment: *What I need is any content.contentID with sectionID equal to 3 and 4.* That's impossible. Do you mean *two* rows that have the same content.contentID and have sectionID equal to 3 and 4 respectively?

Comment: Hi. Yes, so imagine content.contentID is equal to 1 (this is a single article record). This article can be in many different sections. So I want only article records that are in both sections 3 and 4.

Comment: Hi Styu - have a look at http://tinypic.com/r/rjnklz/7 - this shows a cut down version of my results. In this case I would like to somehow establish that Apple and Cherry are in both sections and 3 and 4. Banana and Grape aren't so I don't care about these fruits!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use sub-SELECTs:

```
SELECT *, content.contentID AS thisID
FROM content
LEFT JOIN link_keywords ON content.contentID = link_keywords.contentID
LEFT JOIN link_countries ON content.contentID = link_countries.contentID
LEFT JOIN link_sections ON content.contentID = link_sections.contentID
WHERE status = '1' AND typeID = '1' AND
      content.contentID IN (SELECT section3.contentID
                            FROM link_sections AS section3
                            WHERE sectionID = 3) AND
      content.contentID IN (SELECT section4.contentID
                            FROM link_sections AS section4
                            WHERE sectionID = 4)
GROUP BY contentID
ORDER BY creationDate DESC
```

Comment: Great - I really appreciate the help you have both given me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  *,
  content.contentID AS thisID
FROM content
  LEFT JOIN link_keywords
    ON content.contentID = link_keywords.contentID
  LEFT JOIN link_countries
    ON content.contentID = link_countries.contentID
  LEFT JOIN link_sections
    ON content.contentID = link_sections.contentID
WHERE 
(SELECT COUNT(contentID) AS counter FROM link_sections s2 WHERE s2.contentID=content.contentID AND (sectionID='3' OR sectionID='4') GROUP BY contentID)=2
    AND STATUS = '1'
    AND typeID = '1'
    AND (sectionID = '3'
         OR sectionID = '4')
GROUP BY content.contentID
ORDER BY creationDate DESC;
```

Comment: Hi - yes, I tried that but that brings back contentID's that are in either sectionID 3 or sectionID 4. What I want is items on both sections.

Comment: Edited and now works for the requirements, but [Daniel's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299007/mysql-and-query-on-joined-table/4299205#4299205) is a better one, just leave it here for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is select the rows with sectionID = '3' and intersect the results with the rows with sectionID = '4'.